# Move Tab Bar to top of the screen in android

Tags: android, tabbar

Below I listed the xml code.That shows the tab bar at the bottom of the screen.

**layout_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_home"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_video"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_audio"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_blog"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_gal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_more"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
                android:divider="@null" />

            <!-- android:background="#d8e49c" -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I need to move that tab bar to top of the screen.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Does this work for you....

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_home"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_video"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_audio"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_blog"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_gal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_more"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:divider="@null" />

            <!-- android:background="#d8e49c" -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stephen use this to move your tab on top of the screen in tour tabhost

```
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" >
</TabWidget>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```